# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changedTouches' of undefined

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

```
<div class="carousel">
    <transition-group name="fade" tag="div">
        <div class="carousel" v-for="i in [currentIndex]" :key="i" @touchstart="touchStart()" @touchend="touchEnd()">
            <img :src="currentImg" />
            <button class="btn"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> EXPLORE</button>
            <!--<span class="title">{{images[currentIndex].title}}</span>-->
        </div>
    </transition-group>  
</div>
```

**in my script touchStart method and Touchend method throw this error**

```
methods: {

        startSlide: function() {
            this.timer = setInterval(this.next, 4000);
        },
        jump: function(index){
            clearInterval(this.timer);
            this.currentIndex = index;
            this.startSlide();
        },
        next: function() {
            if(this.currentIndex == this.images.length-1)
            {
                this.currentIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this.currentIndex += 1;
            }
        },
        prev: function() {
            if(this.currentIndex == 0)
            {
                this.currentIndex = this.images.length-1;
            }
            else
            {
                this.currentIndex -= 1;
            }
        },
        touchStart(e){
                touch = e.changedTouches[0];
                this.touchinitial =  parseInt(touch.clientX);
                console.log(this.touchinitial);
                e.preventDefault();
        },
        touchEnd(e){
            touch = e.changedTouches[0];
            this.touchended =  parseInt(touch.clientX);
                console.log(this.touchended);

            if(this.touchinitial > this.touchended)
            {
                    this.next();
            }
            else
            {
                    this.prev();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
```

> What im trying to implement is when the touch start x-coordinate is less than touchend x-coordinate then swipe right else swipe left

**Any help on why i got this error and how to solve**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis on your event listeners. It causes an error since no parameters are passed to the functions.

```
<div class="carousel" v-for="i in [currentIndex]" :key="i" @touchstart="touchStart" @touchend="touchEnd">
```